# HTML flickers on Honeycomb landscape

Tags: android, webview, android-3.0-honeycomb, flicker

When displaying a `WebView` in full screen (`fill_parent` both width and height) in Honeycomb, the HTML flickers an instant when loaded in landscape orientation.

Given this code, you should only see the yellow background (`WebView` color) or the blue background (html body color). But when switching to landscape, you can see the screen partially filled in blue, and behind yellow.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    webView.loadData("<html><body style='background-color:#DDF'><p>Hello world!!!</p></body></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8");
}
```

It's like the HTML was rendered before knowing the container size, and then it gets resized.

This can be reproduced in Android Honeycomb in landscape orientation, both in the emulator and a device.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try disabling hardware acceleration for that activity in the manifest

```
<activity android:name="com.sample.activity"
 android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

Comment: I had the same behavior on a Nexus 4 with Android 4.3. Both orientations until I scrolled the page fully down. Your suggestion worked splendid!

Answer (score 1):

I realize this post of yours is old but I figure input might still be useful. I don't have an actually honeycomb tablet to test the change of orientation but this should work regardless.

I was extremely perplexed by this, but then I noticed the problem. 
Simply change style from "background-color" to just "color":

Comment: That changes the font color, not the background color.

Comment: Anyways, the color's only purpose is to show this weird behaviour of the WebView.

Comment: If I had to guess, it's most likely that Android resizes the container after the rotation is complete, so you get a little bit of delay there and see the yellow background. Again, just a guess.

Comment: how color is related to this? I think this is no way related to this problem